# Google Generative AI text embedding: What `task_type` would be more appropriate for outlier detection use case?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, google-gemini

I am using the Google Generative AI new api. I have a corpus of document and I want to find some outliers. When creating the embeddings what is the most appropriate `task_type` to use? My code resemble the following:

```
model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained("textembedding-gecko-multilingual@001")
text_input = TextEmbeddingInput(text=text, task_type='CLUSTERING')
embeddings = model.get_embeddings([text_input])
```

The available tasks are :

- RETRIEVAL_QUERY: Specifies the given text is a query in a search or retrieval setting.
- RETRIEVAL_DOCUMENT:  Specifies the given text is a document in a search or retrieval setting.
- SEMANTIC_SIMILARITY: Specifies the given text will be used for Semantic Textual Similarity (STS).
- CLASSIFICATION:  Specifies that the embeddings will be used for classification.
- CLUSTERING:  Specifies that the embeddings will be used for clustering.

Not sure what is the most appropriate for an anomaly detection use case.

Comment: is it me or nobody is using stackoverflow anymore since LLMs arrived?